# Couldn't fetch Mysqli_result

Tags: php, mysqli

I've got this error

> **Warning**:  mysqli_fetch_array() [function.mysqli-fetch-array]: Couldn't fetch mysqli_result in **/home/fights7/public_html/include/load_more_home_posts.php** on line **12**

And would like to know what I've done wrong with the below code?

```
$articles_data = mysqli_query($mysqli,"SELECT * FROM streamdata WHERE streamitem_id < '$lastID' ORDER BY streamitem_id DESC LIMIT 10") or die(mysql_error());
while($articles_info = mysqli_fetch_array($articles_data)) {
$json = array();
$json['streamitem_id'] = $articles_info['streamitem_id'];
$json['streamitem_content'] = $articles_info['streamitem_content'];
$json['streamitem_timestamp'] = $articles_info['streamitem_timestamp'];
mysqli_free_result($articles_data);
```

Comment: Hopefully that `$lastID` is properly filtered/sanitized/escaped. Otherwise you're vulnerable to [SQL injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com)

Comment: Yep with msqli_real_escape_string($last_id). Why are people so obsessed with SQL injection on here?

Comment: @dave Because we see lots and lots and lots of truly awful PHP code, and encounter lots and lots of new users who've never even heard of SQL injection :( Better safe than sorry, so we _always_ point it out if we don't explicitly see escaping and filtering in the posted code.

Comment: @dave: my rough estimate is that about 90%+ of php posters here have no clue about injection problems.

Comment: That is fine @MichaelBerkowski, maybe I will start doing the same around the site to help others.

Comment: @dave BTW, not to imply your code is awful, but a lot of PHP code here is, especially on the weekends when it's mostly hobbyists asking questions.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Straight away, it appears that you are calling `mysqli_free_result()` inside your fetch loop, so after the first loop iteration, your result resource has been closed and freed, and no more results will be available.

```
while($articles_info = mysqli_fetch_array($articles_data)) {
  $json = array();
  $json['streamitem_id'] = $articles_info['streamitem_id'];
  $json['streamitem_content'] = $articles_info['streamitem_content'];
  $json['streamitem_timestamp'] = $articles_info['streamitem_timestamp'];
  // Don't do this!
  //mysqli_free_result($articles_data);
}
// If you need to, free it outside the loop
mysqli_free_result($articles_data);
```

I note that you're calling `mysqli_fetch_array()` without specifying `MYSQLI_ASSOC`, and so you're getting both numeric and associative keys back. If you are using everything in your JSON, you don't need to do all those assignments if you use `MYSQLI_ASSOC` or `mysqli_fetch_assoc()`:

```
while($articles_info = mysqli_fetch_assoc($articles_data)) {
  // No need for the $json array. Just use $articles_info directly
  // if you were going to json_encode() it.
}
```